# Is an interval missing one point connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

In my topology book, for a set $S$ of points to be connected, it must be the case that for every 2 disjoint non-empty subsets of $S$ (with their union equaling $S$), there must be a point in one of the 2 sets near the other set.

Now I've read that the only connected subset of the real line are intervals or points, but take the interval $[0,1]$ and remove the point $\frac{1}{2}$. Doesn't this set satisfy the definition of connectedness? Even if we take our disjoint subsets to be $[0,\frac{1}{2}[$ and $]\frac{1}{2},1]$, the biggest point of the first set is near the smallest point of the second. Am I mistaken? Can someone help me understand with nearness how an interval missing a point is not connected?

Comment: Notice that your point $\tfrac12$ is not in either of the disjoint subsets, hence this separation shows that your subspace is **dis**connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of connectedness is a little lacking in detail. A topological space $X$ is [*connected*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) if it **cannot** be expressed in the form $A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, non-empty open subsets of $X$.

Take the topological space $X=[0,1]\setminus\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\}$. Its topology is the [*Euclidean topology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_topology) inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ (the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology)), so that $U\subseteq X$ is open in $X$ iff it is of the form $V\cap X$ for some $V$ open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now the interval $(-1,\frac{1}{2})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, so $(-1,\frac{1}{2})\cap X=[0,\frac{1}{2})$ is open in $X$. Similarly, $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ is open in $X$.

So $X=[0,\frac{1}{2})\cup(\frac{1}{2},1]$ is the union of two disjoint, non-empty open subsets of $X$, and therefore is **dis**connected.